# Critical temperature of Bose-Einstein condensation

Tags: bose-einstein-condensate

It is known (see, e.g. Wikipedia) that the transition to Bose-Einstein condensate occurs below critical temperature:
$$
 T_c \approx 3.3125 \, \frac{\hbar^2 n^{2/3}}{m k_B}
$$
where $n$ is the particle density in the system.

It is obvious that higher particle densities $n$ correspond to higher critical temperature $T_c$.

Nevertheless, it is always stressed that Bose-Einstein condensation has been achieved with ultra low density quantum gases (1/100000 of the density of normal air).

So my question is: Why? Which is the obstacle that prevents experimentalists from trying to Bose-Condense denser gases?